# .htaccess URL rewrite without changing the domain name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, curl, url-rewriting

I want to transfer users from one to the other without knowing them.

like `www.domain1.com/folder` to `www.domain2.com/folder`, but URL remain same `www.doamin1.com/folder`.

I'm sure it's possible with .htaccess but don't know how to do that.

Reason to do this just want to secure my application, don't want to run from client's hosting.

Really appreciate your help.

Comment: As I understand they are completely different domains on different servers. If so -- you have to look at [Reverse Proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy). Check these links: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/proxy.html AND http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html

Comment: did you ever find a simple solution?  I am looking for the same thing, switching subdomains and forcing `https` inside a redirect rule.  It seems as though if you include the full URL for the redirect, it doesn't matter if you leave out the redirect modifier (`[R]`), it'll force the URL change.